# Online resources for understanding credit reports, including a sample?

Tags: united-states, financial-literacy, credit-report, credit-history

Could someone provide me sources where I can find some examples of a credit report (in the USA), how it looks like, etc.?

I want to understand each and every section of credit report.

Any resources/videos that explains credit report will be helpful.

Comment: They usually come with info about how to read the m, and they aren't that complicated ....

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different sources, one from an actual credit reporting agency, Experian.

http://www.experian.com/assistance/sample-credit-report.html

http://www.aie.org/manage-your-money/understand-credit/your-interactive-guide-to-credit-reports.cfm

If what you want to see an actual real credit report, no one in their right mind is going to show you unless they are a close friend or relative.